# Select a second <strong> in a <p> tag?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, parent-child

```html
<p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p><strong>This one</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Is it possible to select the 'This one' text, the second `<p><strong>` and give that a `margin-top`? Or is it not possible? I tried playing around with `p>strong:nth-child(2)` but to no avail.

I know there are empty `<p>`'s inside but that's also the case on the real site as I have no control over the HTML (stuck in CMS / user input)

Comment: You can simply use Id, you know?

Comment: I think this is impossible only ja CSS but you have to use javascript if you can.

Comment: @JackJohnson How so? Im not able to modify the html as I stated in the post

Comment: if the HTML doesnt change, you can use the `:nth-child()` selector by counting which `<p>` tag you have to select

Comment: then you can still select element through its innerHTML, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to create a margin-top for every `strong` tag inside a `p` tag *except* the first `p`, you can use `:not` in the following way:

(note that you have to define it as `inline-block` - otherwise `margin-top` won't apply.

```css
p:not(:first-of-type)>strong {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p><strong>This one</strong></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any reason why :nth-child(2) does not work on this?

Comment: Because it isn't the second child ;-) In your case it would be the 7th child - it's the `p` that counts, not the `strong`. And the `strong` is always the first child of `p`, so you won't be able to use that for selection.

Comment: Oh yeah right, is there any way to select the second `<p>` that has a `<strong>` inside it? I think in sass this would be somewhat 'easier' possible compared to vanilla css?

Comment: No, there is no way for that, since there is no parent selector in CSS, and also no condition like "contains 'xxx' "

Answer (score 0):

You could target the second `strong`:s parent (if the number won't change):

```
p:nth-of-type(7) strong {
   // your css rules
}
```